# Reset Stack which is nested inside my Drawer navigator

Tags: android, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

### **Objective**

Currently, I have a drawer with my various routes

```
Main - Drawer Stack nav
   A - Stack nav
   B - Stack nav
```

I want to replace the routes in `A - Stack nav` when the user clicks a button nested within the drawer component.

Has anyone got pointers on how to achieve this? I've tried using CommonActions however they seem to only be affecting the drawer stack rather than my nested Stack

Comment: please elaborate on what is the desired output in `replace the routes`, in which stack user currently? what action do you want to do? remove screen? replace the user current view?

Comment: @HagaiHarari
I'm aiming to clear the stack or "refresh" it in a sense.

Something similar to this, however, the action will be called from within the Drawer Navigator and shall be affecting a nested Stack Navigator.

`CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { name: 'List' },
      { name: 'View' },
    ],
  })`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue using the code below

```
navigation.dispatch((state:any) => {
  const index = 2;
  const routes = state.routes.filter((r:any) => r.name !== 'people');
  routes.splice(index, 0, {name:'people'});
  return CommonActions.reset({
    ...state,
    routes,
  });
});
navigation.navigate('people')
```

So from the drawer component, the user presses a button which does the following

1. get state
2. removes the route named `people`
3. splices in a new object `{name:"people"}`
4. performs the `CommonActions.reset`

The route named `people` is now refreshed and starts from the beginning.

-- Note--- Change `index` to the index of your route.

This might not be a clean way of doing it and I would be interested to know of a better solution.